# Convert hex string to color

Tags: c#, colors, hex

I am passing a hex value in my QueryString. I'd like to convert that to a color to use the ForeColor in a cell in a grid view. Tried both `System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml()` and `System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb()` with no luck.

My QueryString is urlencoded so the part that matters looks like:

```
QueryString...&color=%23AA4643
```

Below is how I have tried .FromArg:

```
string sColor = Request.QueryString["color"]; // sColor is now #AA4643
Int32 iColorInt = Convert.ToInt32(sColor,16); //Get error message - Could not find any recognizable digits
Color curveColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(iColorInt); //Never makes it here
```

And here is how I have tried .FromHtml:

```
string sColor = Request.QueryString["color"]; 
System.Drawing.Color myColor = new System.Drawing.Color();
myColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(sColor);
```

In this case myColor gets set to - myColor = "{Name=ffaa4643, ARGB=(255, 170, 70, 67)}"

But when I go to use it I get an error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index

Any and all help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
string sColor = Request.QueryString["color"]; // sColor is now #AA4643
Int32 iColorInt = Convert.ToInt32(sColor.Substring(1),16); 
Color curveColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(iColorInt);
```

Comment: Thaks, that gets past the line it was erroring on and sets curveColor to:

curveColor = "{Name=aa4643, ARGB=(0, 170, 70, 67)}"

But when I go to use it in the grid I get same error as other attempt 

"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"

Comment: It means that sometimes you have Request.QueryString["color"] as empty. Please check it under debugger

Comment: SergeyS your solution does in fact work as does my other one. I was so focused on the color I was not looking at where I was setting it. I needed my line to set the color AFTER I called grid.DataBind. There was no Rows in my grid yet...Was so focused on the conversion of the color I overlooked the obvious Thanks! BTW this also works:`System.Drawing.ColorConverter oConverter = new System.Drawing.ColorConverter();` `Color myColor = (Color)oConverter.ConvertFromString(sColor);`